# Rendering texture (video) in OpenGL in a blocking way so my received video frame won't get replaced by new one while rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk

I think that the GTK specifics of this code are not needed to understand what's happening. The `glDraw()` function does OpenGL rendering from the `Frame frame` which is retrieved from `decodedFramesFifo` which is a thread-safe deque.

The .h file

```
class OpenGLArea2 : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    OpenGLArea2();
    ~OpenGLArea2() override;

public:
    Gtk::Box m_VBox{Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, false};
    Gtk::GLArea glArea;

    virtual bool render(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::GLContext> &context){};
};
```

Then the cpp file:

```
OpenGLArea2::OpenGLArea2()
{
    set_default_size(640, 360);

    add(m_VBox);

    glArea.set_hexpand(true);
    glArea.set_vexpand(true);
    glArea.set_auto_render(true);
    m_VBox.add(glArea);

    glArea.signal_render().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &OpenGLArea2::render), false);

    glArea.show();

    m_VBox.show();
}
```

glFlush

```
bool OpenGLArea2::render(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::GLContext> &context)
{
    try
    {
        glArea.throw_if_error();
```

glFlush
            glDraw();

```
        glFlush();
    }
    catch (const Gdk::GLError &gle)
    {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred in the render callback of the GLArea" << std::endl;
        return false;glFlush
    }
}

void OpenGLArea2::run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Important: if decodedFramesFifo does not have any data, it blocks until it has
        Frame frame = decodedFramesFifo->pop_front();
        this->frame = std::move(frame);
        if (!firstFrameReceived)
            firstFrameReceived = true;
        queue_draw();
    }
}
```

Here's a sketch of what glDraw() does:

```
void OpenGLArea2::run()
{
    //Creates shader programs
    //Generate buffers and pixel buffer object to render from
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, textureSize, frame.buffer(j), GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    //calls glTexSubImage2D to do rendering
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting segmentation faults sometimes. I tried debugging with gdb and valgrind, but in gdb it won't show the call stack, just the place where the error ocurred (some memmove weird things) and in valgrind it slows down the application to 1 fps and it simply won't experience the segmentation faults because I think it has plenty of time to render the data before new data arrives.

I suspect that `queue_draw()` isn't blocking, and therefore, it just marks the window for rendering and returns. The window then calls `render()`. If `render()` is fast enough to render before a new frame arrives on the while loop, then no data race occurs. **But if `render()` takes a little bit more time, a new `frame` arrives and is written in the place of the old frame which was in the middle of the rendering**

**So the questions are**: how to render in a blocking way? That is, instead of calling `queue_draw()`, I call directly `glDraw()` and wait for it to return? And can I trust that `glBufferData()` and `glTexSubImage2D()` both consume the `frame` data in a blocking way, and does not simply mark it to be sent to the GPU in a later time?

ps: I found [void Gtk::GLArea::queue_render](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1GLArea.html#a84183c143fe9c2106e683a188fd68a1f)  and [void Gtk::GLArea::set_auto_render(bool auto_render=true)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1GLArea.html#ae345bad1c063aafdb865393e7651eea3) but I think `queue_render()` also returns immediately.

**UPDATE:**

Some people said I should use `glFinish`. The problem is that, in the renderer loop, `queue_draw()` returns immediately, therefore the thread is not blocked at all. How to render without `queue_draw()`?

**UPDATE:**

I added, at the beggining of the while loop:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
```

and at the end of the while loop:

```
conditionVariable.wait(lock);
```

And now my render function is like this:

```
    glArea.throw_if_error();

    glDraw();

    glFinish();

    conditionVariable.notify_one();
```

The conidition variable makes the while loop wait before the rendering finishes, so it can safely delete the received frame (because it goes out of scope). But I'm still receiving segfaults. I added logging to some lines and found out the segfault occurs **while** waiting. What could be the reason?

Comment: "But if render() takes a little bit more time, a new frame arrives and is written in the place of the old frame which was in the middle of the rendering" - Sounds like access to the frame should be guarded by a mutex or similar, so it is *not* possible to modify it while it's being read.

Comment: @JesperJuhl but in the end of a while loop iteration, `frame` gets destroyed, and it's possible it didn't even start to render yet. Even if it did start (not guaranteed, I think), then a mutex wouldn't prevent `frame` from being deleted from memory, rigth?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFinish.xml, also functions with an prefix `gl` should only be OpenGL commands, the same reason you normally don't write custom function in `std::`

Comment: call glFnish at the end of the rendering,not  glFlush();. glFlush makes sure all the commands in the driver are submitted for processing to the GPU. glFinish() makes sure all the commands have been processed.So this one actually blocks till all the rendering logic inside your glDraw() method are done on GPU.

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb I didn't write any function with gl in the beggining. Why did you say that?

Comment: @MichaelIV can you take a look at my update int he question? There's no point in calling `glFinish()` as `queue_draw()` returns immediately. I need to block the thread, but I don't know a way to render without callind `queue_draw`

Comment: Your thread synchronization is just completely broken, and OpenGL has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Where exactly segfault is caused? You should provide mode details. Also,you're using OpenGL wrapper,maybe there is more stuff underneath that needs to me considered here.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs `glDraw`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I suspect that the race condition is not the real problem, without more code, it is rather hard to tell. Maybe just try glFinish at a point where you require that OpenGL is fully ready for the next command. e.g. behind `queue_draw` or at the beginning of `OpenGLArea2::render()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most problematic part:

```
Frame frame = decodedFramesFifo->pop_front();
this->frame = std::move(frame);
```

Since pop_front blocks and waits for frame. If you get a second frame before rendering than the first frame is going to be destroyed with:

```
this->frame = std::move(frame); // this->frame now contains second frame, first frame is destroyed
```

You should lock access to this->frame

```
void ...::run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Frame frame = decodedFramesFifo->pop_front();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mutex};
        this->frame = std::move(frame);
        lk.unlock();
        if (!firstFrameReceived)
            firstFrameReceived = true;
        queue_draw();
    }
}

void ...::render()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mutex};

    // draw 'this->frame'
}
```

Optinaly if you can std::move frame out and you only render once per frame max, you can:

```
void ...::render()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mutex};
    Frame frame = std::move(this->frame);
    lk.unlock();

    // draw 'frame'
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the errors, even though it takes much more time. It seems that the rendering thread stops but my loop continues. Is it possible for the rendering thread segfault but the program continue? The window can't even be resized or closed, but the loop continues